# How to integrate quartz with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to add Quartz to my Spring application. I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-quartz-schedule).

I have a simple Spring app (not Spring boot), so I've added [this configuration](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/spring-quartz/src/main/java/org/baeldung/springquartz/basics/scheduler/QrtzScheduler.java) to my project, along with the class `AutoWiringSpringBeanJobFactory` and the dependency `org.quartz-scheduler:quartz`.

I get the following exception (from [ConfigurationClassEnhancer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java)) when I run my program, which I don't understand:

```
@Bean method QrtzScheduler.springBeanJobFactory called as bean reference for type [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory] but overridden by non-compatible bean instance of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy174]. Overriding bean of same name declared in: com.company.QrtzScheduler
```

Edit: full stackstrace:

```
ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - [ ] -
                 -  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'scheduler' defined in com.company.QrtzScheduler: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'scheduler' parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schedulerFactoryBean' defined in com.company.QrtzScheduler: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'schedulerFactoryBean' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: @Bean method QrtzScheduler.springBeanJobFactory called as bean reference for type [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory] but overridden by non-compatible bean instance of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy174]. Overriding bean of same name declared in: com.company.QrtzScheduler
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:733)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1246)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:881)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4699)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5165)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:970)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1841)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schedulerFactoryBean' defined in com.company.QrtzScheduler: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'schedulerFactoryBean' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: @Bean method QrtzScheduler.springBeanJobFactory called as bean reference for type [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory] but overridden by non-compatible bean instance of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy174]. Overriding bean of same name declared in: com.company.QrtzScheduler
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:591)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1246)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:819)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:725)
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'schedulerFactoryBean' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: @Bean method QrtzScheduler.springBeanJobFactory called as bean reference for type [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory] but overridden by non-compatible bean instance of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy174]. Overriding bean of same name declared in: com.company.QrtzScheduler
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:583)
    ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @Bean method QrtzScheduler.springBeanJobFactory called as bean reference for type [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory] but overridden by non-compatible bean instance of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy174]. Overriding bean of same name declared in: com.company.QrtzScheduler
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.resolveBeanReference(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:420)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:368)
    at com.company.QrtzScheduler$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2a5823dd.springBeanJobFactory(<generated>)
    at com.company.QrtzScheduler.schedulerFactoryBean(QrtzScheduler.java:73)
    at com.company.QrtzScheduler$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2a5823dd.CGLIB$schedulerFactoryBean$4(<generated>)
    at com.company.QrtzScheduler$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2a5823dd$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c9f1b70.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:365)
    at com.company.QrtzScheduler$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2a5823dd.schedulerFactoryBean(<generated>)
    at com.company.QrtzScheduler$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$fdc2031c.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at com.company.QrtzScheduler$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$92cd156a.schedulerFactoryBean(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 42 common frames omitted
```

Can you please help ?

Thanks

Comment: You haven't posted an exception trace. (The message you posted is normally a warning, not an error.)

Comment: It results in a context initialization failure. I've edited my post to add the full stacktrace.